How to add subscription to an existing topic present in another AWS account to the SQS via Terraform
I have the infrastructure for AWS being created using Terraform. There is a SNS topic already present in another AWS account which I have to subscribe for an SQS that I have in my AWS account. How to add this subscription topic to the SQS during resource creation of SQS using Terraform?
As the SNS topic is already present in another account, I just need to refer this subscription to the SQS in my account.
Is there a way to provide subscription arn in the syntax of
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "sqs-resource" 
{

}


Many details are lacking, as well as code examples, but the aws_sns_topic_subscription resource has this note: Setup of cross-account subscriptions from SNS topics to SQS queues requires Terraform to have access to BOTH accounts.
